# Change <p> tag by user input forever

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="content" style="font-size: 25px" placeholder="Name of content"> //The text for p tag
</form>

<p></p> //display the inputted text above right HERE
```

Hey,

I need to make simple thing. Make an input on a website, and under it, make a `<p>` tag. Whatever user inputs to this label/input, it will write that between the `<p>` tag. I know, that there is way in javascript, but i need to make it change forever, that means, when i refresh the page, it will be there, the same message forever. Any way to make it? Better to make it NOT using cross-database systém (in PhP)...

Please help

Comment: PHP + cookies maybe?

Comment: you can use local storage. HTML5 supports it. Although what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Well, making website, workin' like a diary, so i need a input, where user will input his text, than it will appear and stay there

Comment: Forever as in forever or forever as in session? Also don't forget to sanitize it.

Comment: Forever on *any* machine requires a server side technology like PHP/Database

Comment: Well if you need Forever as in Forever, your options are either a db or file i/o. I'd suggest the latter, where your system just creates a file containing header/footer includes and the sanitized input between them. Sounds closer to your use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change it *forever* for every single user, then it's impossible with JavaScript. This is because JavaScript is a client script, and if client scripts could change files' content, then, well, websites wouldn't exist. The best way to do this would be to send a request to [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), either by a `<form>`, or by [AJAX request](http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/).